# ember or showdown : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, showdown

Tom Dayle's Lecture: Intro to Ember 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Ga99hMi7wfY

i used both github.com/cmoel/tom_dale_embe­r_screencast
github.com/cmoel/tom_dale_ember_screencast  And
github.com/jielimanyili/tom-dale-screencast_building-an-app-with-ember-js_code

In Chrome Dev:
**Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined (showdown.js:62) 
If i remove the use of "markdown" from the template.. the App works.

In FireBug:
**a is undefined** (showdown.js: 62)

Not sure if it is Ember or Showdown that is causing this.

Thanks

Comment: Could give some pointer to your app please ? If you can post a jsfiddle/jsbin it would be even better :). you could use http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/7vfLD/ as a starting point. (you must add the external resource for showdown.js)

Comment: Updated fiddel [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7vfLD/4/) Look at lines 56 and 59 in the HTML section, I have changed "{{markdown intro}}" removed markdown. For full page [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7vfLD/4/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will be...little angry... this was just a typo I think... in the template you refer `{{extended}}`, but in the fixtures, the property is `extentded`. So obviously the Showdown plugin complains because you're trying to use it with undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/7vfLD/7/

Comment: Thanks sly7_7. New to Ember just trying out the examples that i can find. First use of jsfiddle too.

Comment: No problem, that was good :). I hope you will continue to enjoy Ember.js

Answer (score 1):

I too followed Tom Dale's youtube video and seemed to get this error only when I refresh the page while on the #/posts/1 (posts/post route).

I managed to resolve this issue by skipping the showdown conversion in the registerBoundHelper, like so:

```
var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('markdown', function(input) {

  // Add this part
  if (typeof input == 'undefined')  return;

  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});
```